# NSMutableAttributedString show wrong syntax with Arabic language

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsattributedstring

I used `NSMutableAttributedString` to format a string as follows:

```
NSString* nextPrayerString=@"للفجر";
NSMutableAttributedString *nextPrayerAttString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:nextPrayerString];
UIFont *nextPrayerNameFont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:21.0f];
[nextPrayerAttString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:nextPrayerNameFont range:NSMakeRange(0,[nextPrayerString length])];
```

but on runtime the string appears as the image below:

[image]

and i expect it to appear as i wrote it "للفجر" , please i need help.

Comment: It can be font related but it can be due to Unicode characters in your string. They are sometimes not visible and can cause the attributed string to break the words like this. You can edit your string here http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/photoshop-arabic/ to eliminate the Unicode character. After each word press the delete button and if it doesn't delete any part of the word then it means there was a Unicode character that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you're using Helvetica as the font for Arabic text.
Helvetica likely lacks the proper ligatures & combinations to display the correct character variations for the Arabic text. Geeza Pro is the default Arabic font for iOS - maybe try that instead?

From [Apple's NSAttributedString Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/ChangingAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000162-176048-BBCDHCDJ):
"Scripts may only be assigned fonts that support them. For example, Kanji and Arabic characters can’t be assigned the Times-Roman font, and must be reassigned fonts that support these scripts."